# TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined 'react_devtools_backend.js:2574'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, redux, azure-devops

I am getting this error is production for react web application. me not able to find the issue can someone please help me. me getting the blank page as result. but if i reload the page then it works fine.

Below I am sharing the error page also.

[image]

Router.jsx

```
function Router() {
  const {systemResourceIds, userPageAccess} = useSelector(state=> state?.getUser);
  const systemResources = userPageAccess?.systemResources ;
  let setSystemResourceIdObject = systemResourceIds;
  let routes =(setSystemResourceIdObject)? createRoute(setSystemResourceIdObject):setSystemResourceIdObject;
  let defaultRoute = ''; 
  const componentIdMapping = {
    "SR-001":ExecutiveDashBoard,
    "SR-008":Admin,
    "SR-002":ProjectList,
    "SR-007":FileUpload,
    "SR-003":ProjectProfile,
    "SR-0013":UserRoleAssignment,
    "help":Help,
    "SR-0021":MonitoringList,
    "SR-0022":CreateMonitoringList
  };

  (routes) && routes?.forEach(route=>{
    if(componentIdMapping[route.id]){
      route["component"]=componentIdMapping[route.id];
    }
  });
  
  if (systemResources && systemResources.length > 0) {
    if (typeof setSystemResourceIdObject !=="undefined" && setSystemResourceIdObject["SR-001"]) {
      defaultRoute = '/executivedashboard';
    } else if (typeof setSystemResourceIdObject !=="undefined" && setSystemResourceIdObject["SR-002"]) {
      defaultRoute = '/projectlist';
    } else if (typeof setSystemResourceIdObject !=="undefined" && (setSystemResourceIdObject["SR-007"])) {
      defaultRoute = '/fileupload';
    } else if (typeof setSystemResourceIdObject !=="undefined" && setSystemResourceIdObject["SR-008"]) {
      defaultRoute = '/admin';
    }
  }    
  const generalAccess = () => {  
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact strict path="/" render={() => <Redirect to={defaultRoute} />} />
        {
          (routes) && routes.map(route=>(route.access) ? 
            <Route key = {route.id} exact strict path ={route.link} component={route.component}/>
           :
            <Route key = {route.id} exact strict path ={route.link} render={() => <Error statusCode={403} /> } />
          )
        }
        <Route exact strict path="/monitoringlist/project/:id" component = {MoninoringListProjects} />
        <Route exact strict path="/monitoringlist/edit/:id" component = {EditMonitoringList} />
        <Route exact strict path="/monitoringlist/report/:id" component = {MoninoringListProjects} />
        <Route exact strict path="/monitoringlist/addprojects/:id" component = {AddProjects} />
        <Route exact strict path="/monitoringlist/projectdetails/:id/:key" component = {MLProjectDetailsInfo} />
        <Route path="*" render={() => <Error statusCode={400}/>}/>         
      </Switch>
    );
  };
 
  return generalAccess();
}

export default Router;
```

Comment: If you don't add code in the form of a [mcve] we can't help you. The error is clear though. Whatever you're trying to loop over is `undefined`.

Comment: Try to debug in development mode. Your code is not complete to reproduce the issue.

Comment: in development mode it is working fine only in production it is not working

Comment: I got a similar problem: everything works in dev mode, but production build shows the error:
`react_devtools_backend.js:2574 Error: "n" is read-only`

Looks like react devtools is giving problems, node the code itself...

Comment: ...ok, in my case, the culprit was somewhere inside Material UI DataGrid component and the problem was gone after `npm update` everything to latest versions (with eyes closed and fingers crossed)